# I want to block special characters and display error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i am trying set up a code which show fade out error message when we enter non alphanumeric character and replace that character with null ,its work well on other special characters (without shift key).

> But special character like #(with shift key eg: shift + # ) the error
>   message fade out very quickly almost invisible

thats my issue how can i solve it?

this is my code

```js
function NonAlphaNumericup(){
            value = document.getElementById("${formCliUserUsername}").value;
    if( /[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/.test( value ) ) 
   {
                value = value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/,'');
                document.getElementById("${formCliUserUsername}").value = value;
                $("#error-text").text("Username may only contain alphanumeric and hyphen");
                $("#error-msg").css("display", "block");
                $("#error-msg").fadeOut( 2500, function() {
                        $("#error-msg").css("display", "none");
                    });
                    return false;      
   }
   else{
                $("#error-msg").css("display", "none");
                return true;
   }
        }
```

```html
                    <td><input type="text" name="$formCliUserUsername" value="$user" id="$formCliUserUsername" onkeydown="NonAlphaNumeric()" ></td>
```

Comment: Please explain in details with example.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is not a code writing service, you need to start by making an effort yourself.

Comment: Please provide you code , what you have tried.
Please do not discourage new contributor by giving negative marking.

Answer (score 1):

you can do as below:

```
    var timer = '';
    var oldValue='';
    $("input#username").keyup(function() {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      var self=$(this);
      var newValue=$(self).val();
      $(this).val(oldValue);
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
               $(self).val(newValue);
               oldValue=newValue;
      }, 3000); 
    });
```